# ShiroFilter invalidRequest HTTP 400 errors

Tags: java, shiro, tomcat9

We use Shiro (v1.7) and have recently begun seeing lots of /ShiroFilter 'InvalidRequest' Http 400 errors on our NewRelic monitoring.   We're not seeing exceptions in the application log though and it doesn't appear to impact the application or performance.

What is the cause of these and how can they be muted?   (note: we do not use or need urlReWriting)

Comment: What does the request URL look like?  Are you handling internal, external traffic, or both? Also take a look at: https://shiro.apache.org/web.html#global-filters

Comment: The URL is /ShiroRequest and we handle external traffic.  Interestingly, there are no exceptions in catalina.out or the applications log4j file.   But NewRelic is reporting it in large numbers.